# read multiple Json data from webservice

Tags: c#, json, web-services

i have a web service that returns a Json string.
my problem is that i have difficulties to read it

i tried with:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<CinfoRichiesta>>(jsonData);
```

but how can i get values from "students" and "locations"?
with javascript i used :"   var j = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);" but i think with c# code would be different

this is an example of string:

```
{"Questions":{
    "id":"2",
    "BOOK":"3",
        "students":{
        "class":"3",
        "theme","43"
        },
        "locations":{
        "h":"0",
        "L":"3"
        }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing to a collection of type `CinfoRichiesta`, which should hold a property value for `students` and `locations`.

Assuming that your JSON is correctly formatted and your class definition is suitable for the response (I recommend double checking it by pasting the **entire** response string into [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com))

Once that's all validated, you should be able to see the `students` and `locations` collections internally like so:

```
foreach(Question q in myobj)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(q.students.class)
}
```

which should give you the result of `3`.

*edit*

I think your main question is why you're unable to access the properties of `students` and `locations`. Make sure `Students` is its own class as such:

```
public class Students
{
    public int class { get; set; }
    public int theme { get; set; }
}
```

and your `locations` class should be:

```
public class Locations
{
    public int h { get; set; }
    public int l { get; set; }
}
```

You should then have a `questions` class that instaniates both `students` and `locations`, as such:

```
public class Questions
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int book { get; set; }
    public Student students { get; set; }
    public Locations locations { get; set; }
}
```

When working with JSON deserialization, it's important that your object property names (ie `class`) match the response string in terms of case. So If you wrote it as `public int Theme`, it won't directly map.

Slightly annoying in terms of coding standards, but hey ho :-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your JSON isn't valid so thats the first problem you have. You can verify this at http://jsonlint.com/ for example.

i have currently fixed this in the following way:

```
{
    "Questions": {
        "id": "2",
        "BOOK": "3",
        "students": {
            "class": "3",
            "theme": "na",
            "43": "na"
        },
        "locations": {
            "h": "0",
            "L": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

Second your class should be correct, with the current JSON this should look something like this

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Questions Questions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Questions
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string BOOK { get; set; }
        public Students students { get; set; }
        public Locations locations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Students
    {
        public string _class { get; set; }
        public string theme { get; set; }
        public string _43 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Locations
    {
        public string h { get; set; }
        public string L { get; set; }
    }
```

After this you can deserialize it like this

```
var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<Rootobject>>(jsonData);
```

And then you can get the information like this

```
myobj.Questions.students._class
```

Comment: Great it is very nice